# How to animate an ImageButton into invisibility

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, alpha-transparency

This is a follow up to [Animate ImageView from alpha 0 to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281246/animate-imageview-from-alpha-0-to-1).

I have an ImageButton that I want to animate into view when user does X and then animate out of view when user does Y. Animating **into** view is working fine. But animating out of view is kind of not working. In fact it is working, in that the animation happens. But after the button fades out of view, it pops back as VISIBLE. So I use this code

```
AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.9f, 0.0f);
        animation1.setDuration(5000);
        animation1.setStartOffset(1000);
        animation1.setFillAfter(true);
        animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                GVLog.d(TAG,"MAKE INVISIBLE onAnimationStart: %s",tokenBtn.getVisibility());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                GVLog.d(TAG,"MAKE INVISIBLE onAnimationRepeat: %s",tokenBtn.getVisibility());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                tokenBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                GVLog.d(TAG,"MAKE INVISIBLE onAnimationEnd: %s",tokenBtn.getVisibility());

            }
        });
        tokenBtn.startAnimation(animation1);
```

but the call to make the ImageButton invisible is not taking effect. So how do I make it take effect so that the ImageButton remains invisible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173890/how-to-animate-setvisibility-for-an-imagebutton-on-android

Comment: It appears I may need to add that the image in the ImageButton is itself an animating GIF.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. These codes always work on my apps.

```
AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
animation1.setDuration(1000);

tokenBtn.startAnimation(animation1);
tokenBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Your suggestion behaves the same as when I put it inside `onAnimationStart`. And the problem with that approach is if the image is a GIF it stops animating as it fades away.